# How do I put compiled JavaScript Code into my HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, coffeescript

Can anyone tell me how/where to put this code in a basic html page:

```
var autoSizeText;
autoSizeText = function() {
  var el, elements, _i, _len, _results;
  elements = $('.resize');
  console.log(elements);
  if (elements.length < 0) {
    return;
  }
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = elements.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    el = elements[_i];
    _results.push((function(el) {
      var resizeText, _results1;
      resizeText = function() {
        var elNewFontSize;
        elNewFontSize = (parseInt($(el).css('font-size').slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px';
        return $(el).css('font-size', elNewFontSize);
      };
      _results1 = [];
      while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
        _results1.push(resizeText());
      }
      return _results1;
    })(el));
  }
  return _results;
};
```

I got the code from this link: [Here.](https://coderwall.com/p/_8jxgw) And I am trying to utilize the Javascript Compiled code part, because I simply don't know how to use CoffeeScript yet.

Thanks guys.

Other info: So far I have tried to put the compiled code right before the end body tag and put the code into script tags but it is still not working. I am trying to use the code because I have text in a responsive div (ie: divcontainingtext { width: 80%; height:20%; }) that I would like to be responsive. Also, I have tried using FitText and it has not solved my issue (the text still overflows from the containing div and the text just isn't responsive enough to me; I know I could use the overflow style to make the text not overflow but I am not looking for scroll bars).

Edit: I have put the code into script tags right before my ending body tag. I also have put

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in my head tags.

Comment: `autoSizeText` is a `function`, you need to call the function `autoSizeText();` - and you also need `jQuery` too.

Comment: It looks like it requires a query selector engine, do you have `zepto` or `jQuery` loaded?

Comment: How would I load zepto? I loaded Jquery but that doesn't seem to work. Also, it looks like autosizetext is already being declared a function? If I am wrong, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Yes it has been declared as a `function`, but it's not being `called`/ `instantiated` ;-)

Comment: Also, just to mention, that using the protocol agnostic `src="//` won't work if you run the file directly from `file:///` - you would need to specify `http://` when loading `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="no-resize">This text won't be resized and will go out of the div.</div>
    <div class="resize">hout of the div.</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

var autoSizeText;
autoSizeText = function() {
  var el, elements, _i, _len, _results;
  elements = $('.resize');
  console.log(elements);
  if (elements.length < 0) {
    return;
  }
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = elements.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    el = elements[_i];
    _results.push((function(el) {
      var resizeText, _results1;
      resizeText = function() {
        var elNewFontSize;
        elNewFontSize = (parseInt($(el).css('font-size').slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px';
        return $(el).css('font-size', elNewFontSize);
      };
      _results1 = [];
      while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
        _results1.push(resizeText());
      }
      return _results1;
    })(el));
  }
  return _results;
};

autoSizeText(); // here is where we call the function.

</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .no-resize, .resize {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 15px
}
</style>
```

Also, make sure you load `jQuery` too.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Great work, I think it was the Jquery I forgot to source, and calling the function at the end. Thank you.

Comment: You should point him to some basic tutorials on the structure of web pages.

Answer (score 1):

Put this script to a file save it by the ending myScript.js (best case in a folder called js)

**In your HTML Code**

link the myScript.js by

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myScript.js"></script>
```

in the html , if the script is in the js folder.

Answer (score 1):

Put the script within `<script></script>` tag in header or footer.  Also add the following before `</script>` tag.

```
 $(document).ready -> autoSizeText()
```

You need to modify above for jquery `$(document).ready(function()`.

Example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mn4rr/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `script` tag:

**Option 1:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var autoSizeText;
    ...
      return _results;
    };  
  </script>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

**Option 2 (recommended)**. Save the js code to a js file, for example `someScript.js`, and then load it like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="someScript.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

The path specified in `src` is relative to your `.html` file, in this example both files are in the same directory. If the js was saved for example in a `scripts` folder, the path would be `src="scripts/someScript.js"`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here.

**First**

The code only creates a function.  You will need to call that function as well:

```
autoSizeText();
```

**Second**

The code is looking for elements with a class of responsive.  The div you mentioned has a class of div containing text.  You will need to change either the div's class or the code.

Answer (score -1):

Did you put the code inside script tags when you were placing it before the closing body tag? The browser still needs to know it's javascript when placed in the body.

If you put the code in the head tags, then the .resize element doesn't exist yet when running the code. If you put it within script tags at the end of the page body, then everything is loaded and the code should work, baring coding errors.

Additionally, you are calling jQuery, so you'll need to add the following script within your head tag to reference jQuery.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Last but not least, make sure to call autoSizeText(); after the existing code.